# Matching dates in sqldf

Tags: r

I have a data frame with stock data (date, symbol, high, low, open, close, volume). Using [r](/questions/tagged/r) and mysql and sqldf and rmysql I have a list of unique dates and unique stock symbols.
What I need now is to loop through the data and find the close on two specified dates.  For instance:

- `stkData` contains (date, symbol, high, low, open, close, volume)
- `dates` contains unique dates
- `symbol` contains unique symbols

I want to loop through the lists in a sqldf statement as such:

```
'select stkData$close from stkData where symbol = symbol[k] and date = dates[j]'
```

`k` and `j` would be looped numbers, but my problem is the `symbol[k]` and `dates[j]` parts.
sqldf won't read them properly (or I can't code properly).  I've tried `as.Date`, `as.character` with no luck.  I get the following error message:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "[4,]": syntax error)
```

Comment: I think you are confusing SQL syntax and R syntax.

Comment: Example 5 on the sqldf home page https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf shows how to use the fn$ facility to insert variables into an sql string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty far off in terms of syntax for sqldf, unfortunately. You can't use `$` or `[]` notations in sqldf calls because those are both R syntax, not SQL syntax. It's an entirely separate language. What's happening is that sqldf is taking your data frame, importing it into SQLite3, executing the SQL query that you supply against the resulting table, and then importing the result set back into R as a data frame. No R functionality is available within the SQL.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but if you want to run multiple queries in a loop, you probably want to construct the SQL query as a string using the R function `paste()`, so that when it gets to SQLite3 it'll just be static values where you currently have `symbol[k]` and `dates[j]`.

So, you'll have something like the following, but wrapped in a loop for `j` and `k`:

```
sqldf(paste('select close from stkData where symbol = ', symbol[k],
            ' and date = ', dates[j]))
```

Comment: Great thank you! (A couple tweaks: 1) I had to use " instead of ' and 2) I had to throw a 'seq=""' at the end to get rid of extra spacing inside the quotes.)  Again thanks very much it saved me a ton of frustration!

Comment: Happy to help. Could you click the check mark on the left to accept my answer so the question won't show up as still being open? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to construct the select statement as a string with paste before it gets passed to your SQL caller. Something like:

```
combo_kj <- expand.grid(ksym=symbol[1:k], jdates=dates[1:j])

SQLcalls <- paste('select close from stkData where symbol = ',
                   combo_kj$ksym,
                   ' and date = '
                   combo_kj$jdates,
                   sep="")
```

And then loop over SQLcalls with whatever code you are using.

Comment: I've never used this method before.  How would you loop over SQLcalls?  Thank you by the way.

Comment: SQLcalls is just are a character vector; same type as were the results of paste(). So: res <- list(); for( idx in seq_along(SQLcalls)) { res[idx] <- sqldf(SQLcalls[idx]) }

Answer (score 0):

Preface `sqldf` with `fn$` as shown and then strings within backticks will be replaced by the result of running them in R and strings of the form $variable will be replaced by the contents of that variable (provided the variable name contains only word characters).  Note that SQL requires that character constants be put in quotes so be sure to surround the backticks or $variable with quotes:

```
fn$sqldf("select close from stkData 
   where symbol = '`symbol[k]`' and 
         date = '`dates[j]`' ")
```

To use the $variable syntax try this:

```
mysymbol <- symbol[k]
mydate <- dates[j]
fn$sqldf("select close from stkData 
   where symbol = '$mysymbol' and 
         date = '$mydate' ")
```

Also see example 5 on the sqldf github page: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf